# NiFi forward/duplicate TCP Stream

Tags: tcp, stream, apache-nifi

I'm supposed to duplicate a binary TCP Stream.

So I set up a NiFi 1.9.0 server, put in a ListenTCP processor and a PutTCP processor, configured the proper IPs and Ports and connected them.

So far so good, the packets were received by the ListenTCP processor and also forwareded by the PutTCP processor.

But NiFi seems to mess around with the data somehow, the sent packets aren't exactly the same as received. I expected NiFi to just forward everything 1:1 but something is happening and I cannot find out what.

I've been playing around with the Character Set, Max Batch Size and Batching Message Delemiter settings on the ListenTCP processor and also with the Outgoing Message Delemiter and Character Set on the PutTCP processor.

I also messed around with a MergeContent processor but didn't get it to work properly.

Here you can see the difference between received (red) and sent data (captured using tcpflow).

[Link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxZ7v.png)
[image]

Another problem is that I don't really know the data I'm processing, it says in the documentation:

> These log files are in the machine-readable binary format that is described by the XML file called ebm.xml.

and

> The streamed events are in the TCP-based binary format.

I do have access to ebm.xml file, but not sure how I can make use of it.

Anyone an idea how I can get NiFi to simply forward everything?
I'm new to NiFi, so I might have missed some possibilites...

Answer (score 1):

The ListenTCP processor reads data from the stream using a new-line character as a logical message separator. For example, if the stream had:

```
<chunk1><new-line><chunk2><new-line><chunk3><new-line>
```

It would result in reading chunk1, chunk2, and chunk3 into an internal queue.

When it writes them back out it uses the outgoing message delimiter. So the outgoing flow file would be:

```
<chunk1><outgoing-delim><chunk2><outgoing-delim><chunk3><outgoing-delim>
```

Unfortunately it is more geared towards receiving textual data such as logs which are typically line-delimited. The chunks should be passing through unaltered as byte[], but typically binary data wouldn't have these logical new-line boundaries, so I'm not sure how well it works for that.

Comment: Hm so if I want to forward everything unmodified, I would choose the same delemiters in ListenTCP and PutTCP, right?
I didn't manage to find an appropriate delemiter yet, looks like I'm goning to create a little Python Script.
Or is there any software thats capable of multiplying binary TCP Streams? Maybe Kafka?

Comment: In order to use Kafka you still need to read the TCP stream into some type of logical messages and then write them to Kafka using a producer that understands the Kafka protocol.

Comment: It probably could be done with a custom NiFi processor that transferred bytes directly from the receiving connection to an outbound connection, its just not what the current set of processors was really geared towards.